# How to prove there is no rational number r that satisfies $6^r=10$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that there is no rational number r that satisfies $6^r=10$.

I got to the following:

Suppose r = $a/b$, which would give $6^{a/b} = 10$

Taking the b-th power of both sides would give : $6^a = 10^b$

However, I'm stuck here.. how do I finish my proof? Can anyone explain maybe?

Comment: $3$ divides the left hand but not the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle r=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ are $b$ are integers.

Then

\begin{align*}
6^\frac{a}{b}&=10\\
6^a&=10^b\\
2^a3^a&=2^b5^b
\end{align*}

By the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic,
$a=b$, $a=0$ and $b=0$. This is impossible.